# How to take off line numbers in Vi?

Tags: editor, numbers, vi

For displaying line numbers in a file, I use command:

```
set numbers
```

What is the command to clear line numbers from the file?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

If you are talking about show line number command in **[vi/vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_line_numbers)**

you could use

> set nu

in commandline mode to turn on and

> set nonu

will turn off the line number display or

> set nu!

to toggle off display of line numbers

Comment: If relative line numbers are enabled, you have to: `set relativenumber! nu!`.

Comment: But once you close and open the file again, the numbers show up again. How can I permanently remove the line numbers?

Comment: @jobs, I think you have to have the line in your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 22):

Display line numbers:

```
:set nu
```

Stop showing the line numbers:

```
:set nonu
```

Its short for :set nonumber

ps. These commands are to be run in normal mode.

Answer (score 16):

To turn off line numbering, again follow the preceding instructions, except this time enter the following line at the  :  prompt:

```
set nonumber
```

Answer (score 9):

For turning off line numbers, any of these commands will work:

1. :set nu!
2. :set nonu
3. :set number!
4. :set nonumber

Comment: these commands works inside vim, but not in .vimrc. I have `set nonu` in ~/.vimrc, but the vim still have line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

**Easily Display Line number:**

> set number flag (to show line number type)

`:set nu` **or** `:set number`

> to unset the number flag (hide the line number type)

```
:set nu!
```

**If you need number every time you start `vi/vim`, append following line to your `~/.vimrc` file:**

```
set number
```

**Open a file at particular location/line number**

```
$ vi +linenumber file.rb
$ vi +300 initlib.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set nonumber
set norelativenumber
```

If you are using some vim bundles.

Answer (score 0):

From the Document "[Mastering the VI editor](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/editors/vi/vi.html)":

```
number (nu)
Displays lines with line numbers on the left side.
```

Comment: The link no longer has that document

Answer (score 0):

`set number`
`set nonumber`

**DO** work inside `.vimrc` and make sure you DO NOT precede commands in `.vimrc` with `:`

Answer (score 0):

write command in terminal:

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

for set the number:
write **set number**

for remove number:
write **set nonumber**